# Laravel - Diference between Model::lists('id') and Model::all()->lists('id')?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel 4, what is the difference between the two forms below to make the query using the call `lists`?

Example:

```
class User extends Eloquent {}

User::all()->lists('id'); #first method

User::lists('id'); #second method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method equates to

```
SELECT * FROM `users`;
```

Followed by running the below on the collection.

```
array_pluck($this->items, $value, $key);
```

The second method equates to

```
SELECT `id` FROM `users`;
```

Both will give you an array in which the values are that from the `id` column, but the latter only retrieves the relevant information from the database.

N.B. Whilst the question is tagged laravel-4, it is also worth noting that this has changed in 5.1 for those who happen upon this answer. `lists` in Laravel >= 5.1 returns a Collection instance instead of a plain array.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the first method will instantiate a bunch of `User` objects and populate a `Collection` with them, then iterate over the collection to obtain the ids.

Comment: @nCrazed valid point. To expand on your point for those who aren't sure about the consequences of this- memory consumption will increase, and it will be a much slower method of obtaining a list of IDs as a result.